# Java - How do I call a class's method with a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use my input from the console to pick which class's main method I want to run. 
    package run;

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;
import testing.*;

public class run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "testing."+input.nextLine();
        Class Program = Class.forName(name);
        //Try 1
        Program obj = new Program();
        //Got error "Program cannot be resolved to a type" on program and program
        //Try 2
        Program.main();
        //Got error "The method main() is undefined for the type Class" on main
        //Try 3
        Class.forName(name).main();
        //Got error "The method main() is undefined for the type Class<capture#2-of ?>" on main

    }
}
```

Comment: You're naming of types and references is not appropriate

Comment: Does it implement an interface? Is the method static?

Comment: The compiler is getting confused by reference and type name

Comment: Do some research into “reflection” - then decide on a better solution

Comment: The method is static What do you mean by the compiler is getting confused by reference and type name? I can try researching reflection.

Comment: `Class.forName(name).getMethod("main").invoke(null)`

Comment: Thanks. I should have read the reflection docs first but they looked intimidating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class program = Class.forName(name);
program.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, new Object[]{args});
```

provide your `main` method is `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved easily using [Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection). Check out the code below:

```
package run;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;
import testing.*;

public class run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, NegativeArraySizeException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "testing."+input.nextLine();
        Class program = Class.forName(name);

        program.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, Array.newInstance(String.class, 0));

    }
}
```